# GridView Table 1 related to Table 2

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

Sorry I know Title is really confusing but I couldn't figure out what exactly to put down.

Basically I created a Grid View which queries database and displays data. It works perfectly, no complain, however what I have right now is,

[image]

but what I want is,

[image]

Question: I am not sure how can I do this, can someone just point me out in right direction please ?

I think I will going to use nested gridviews.

Comment: If you were using say an EntityDataSource you could put a ListView in the end coloumn and bind its items to the Navigation proprty if you set up your database and EF model well. .Net2.0 really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your `SELECT` Query like below... It will you to get the **Expected Result**...

**SQL Fiddle :** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00b5f/15

I have named the `Table` as `Fruits`

```
SELECT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID,
stuff(
(
    SELECT ','+ [FruitTitle] FROM fruits WHERE CrateID = t.CrateID FOR XML path('')
),1,1,'') Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID FROM fruits )t
```

**OR**

`CREATE a PROC`

`*Place this Query in that Proc*`

`*Call that Proc*`

`*assign that Result set to GridView*`

You can Assign he Stored Proc Result set to GridView by using the Below Code :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string spName = "YOURStoredProcudureName";


            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //display the DataTable to a Data control like GridView for example
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Fetch Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: @user13814 : Thanks, If it helps you then mark it as answer, Then only it was easily identify to Others..

Comment: Pandian, what if I want to get fruit weight as well, which is already a column in view

Comment: @user13814: IS it have different value on each row...?

Comment: In the second select statement, I tried to add fruit weight, but it doesn't seem to work and only shows me result as  FruitWeight>, Mango 7

Comment: it was syntax error which I fixed it thanks, I still got another question but I will ask another question for it

Comment: I added a new question, if you know anything would be great, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219592/gridview-hyperlink-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This is more an sql (or whatever langue your database engine uses) problem than a c# problem although one solution from c# would be (though it may be a bit of extra work) to use a html literal to draw you table at run time

the other option would be to change your sql but without more information i can't say if you could perhaps use a group by on changeID or a pivot table

Comment: or maybe use this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189997/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-asp-net-Csharp