# How to create a HyperLink field out of SQL query

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

In reference to this question of mine,

[GridView Table 1 related to Table 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217674/gridview-table-1-related-to-table-2/16218281?noredirect=1#comment23195878_16218281)

I got a gridview which looks like this at the moment,

[image]

Here is the SQL [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a49/3)

**Question:**

How Can I create a HyperLinkField with FruitTitle and link to fruit website ?

This is the code I am using for displaying `Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate` at the moment and works perfectly,

```
            BoundField theField = new BoundField();
            theField.DataField = "Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate";
            gv.Columns.Add(theField);
```

what to put in

```
            HyperLinkField theField = new HyperLinkField();
            theField.DataTextField = 'Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate';
            theField.DataNavigateUrlFields = // not sure ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Literal control instead of Hyperlink and then try using below Query:

```
SELECT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID,
stuff(
(
  SELECT '<a href=''' + [FruitWebsite] + ''' target=''_blank''>'+ [FruitTitle] +'</a>'
  FROM fruits WHERE CrateID = t.CrateID FOR XML path('')
),1,1,' ') Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID FROM fruits )t
```

Comment: +1, Thanks but sorry as it's not working as I wanted bro, it shows me URL next to fruitTitle when I just want fruitTitle as HyperLink field

Comment: No it should show you just the FruitTitle as Hyperlink, did you use Literal control and bound it to this result?

Comment: didn't worked for me but I used this one instead, http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/

Answer (score 2):

Try like below, it will help you...

**SQL FIDDLE :**  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a49/18

**SQL :**

```
SELECT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID,
stuff(
(
    SELECT ',<a href=''' + [FruitWebsite] + ''' target=''_blank''>'+ [FruitTitle] +'</a>' FROM fruits WHERE CrateID = t.CrateID FOR XML path('')
),1,1,' ') Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID FROM fruits )t
```

Also,  Add **HTML ENCODE = FALSE** in your Code then only the HTML functionality reflect in your Grid View

**C# :**

```
    BoundField theField = new BoundField();
    theField.DataField = "Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate";
    theField.HtmlEncode = false;
    gv.Columns.Add(theField);
```

Comment: +1, Thanks but sorry as it's not working as I wanted sir, it shows me URL next to fruitTitle when I just want fruitTitle as HyperLink field

Comment: I might need to use ASP:HyperLink  tag instead of html