# How to form hyperlink in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hyperlink

I would like to create a hyperlink as one of the results from my sql query. It would take data from three columns (a, b, and c) and return a click link with the address "http://soandso.com/blah/Planets.aspx?dln=a&Year=b&ein=c" with a, b, and c in the hyperlink corresponding to the values for columns a, b, and c in the specified row. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219592/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-field-out-of-sql-query

Comment: that's a formatting issue: put the logic in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using string concatenation.

With SQL Server 2012+ you can use the `concat` function:

```
select 
 concat('http://soandso.com/blah/Planets.aspx?dln=', a, '&Year=', b, '&ein=', c) as url
from your_table
```

Note that this just return the url as a string; to show it as a hyperlink you have to add the appropriate html tags, but that should probably be done in the presentation layer of your application.

With older versions you have to use `+` and possibly cast values to the correct type.