# href is not showing as HyperLink in GridView

Tags: c#, webforms

In reference to these questions of mine,

[How to create a HyperLink field out of SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219592/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-field-out-of-sql-query)

[GridView Table 1 related to Table 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217674/gridview-table-1-related-to-table-2/16218281?noredirect=1#comment23195878_16218281)

If I run this SQL query then I get something like this,

```
SELECT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID,
stuff(
(
    SELECT ',<a href=''' + [FruitWebsite] + ''' target=''_blank''>'+ [FruitTitle] +'</a>' FROM fruits WHERE CrateID = t.CrateID FOR XML path('')
),1,1,' ') Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID FROM fruits )t
```

[image]

But my GridView is not displaying what I want, I want a **HyperLink** whereas my gridview is not taking this `<a href='www.mango1.com' target='_blank'>Mango 1</a>` as a HyperLink.

Now if I try this,

```
SELECT ',<asp:HyperLink ID='sadasdasdas' + [FruitWebsite] + ''' target=''_blank''>'+ [FruitTitle] +'</a>' FROM fruits WHERE CrateID = t.CrateID FOR XML path('')
),1,1,' ') Types_of_Fruits_in_Crate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID FROM fruits )t
```

Then I start getting errors as Syntax is not right.

**Try fiddle if you want** : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a49/18

Comment: This is a terrible title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a HyperLink field out of SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219592/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-field-out-of-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you changing the SQL to output hyperlinks in full?

Surely you should use the GridView control to do this with a `HyperLinkColumn`, so SQL:

```
SELECT CrateTitle,CrateDescription,CrateID,FruitWebsite,FruitTitle
FROM fruits
-- WHERE CrateID = ? -- add criteria if needed
```

Then the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView id="grd" runat="server">
    <columns>
     <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="FruitTitle"
        datanavigateurlfields="FruitWebsite"
        datanavigateurlformatstring="{0}"          
        headertext="Linky link"
        target="_blank" />
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### edit

---

You can add this dynamically if you wish in codebehind:

```
HyperLinkField hlf = new HyperLinkField();
hlf.datatextfield = "FruitsTitle"; // Or a string variable
hlf.datanavigateurlfields="FruitWebsite"; // Or a string variable
hlf.datanavigateurlformatstring="{0}"; // Or a string variable          
hlf.headertext="Linky link"; // Or a string variable
hlf.target = "_blank";

GrdiView grd = new GrdiView();

grd.columns.add(hlf);
```

This is all off the top of my head, as I've no IDE in front of me so some of the syntax may be out or need capitals etc... But the concept is that you can define a column in codebehind, add it to a GridView, either defined in codebehind or on the page, then bind the data and you're off!

Comment: Thanks, but I am creating GridView at runtime using c#

Comment: Then use this same concept in the codebehind? `grd.columns.add(hyperlinkcol)` - all the same properties are available to dynamically created columns: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

Comment: getting error when I try it your way, System.Web : A field or property with the name 'FruitWebsite' was not found on the selected data source. :    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField.OnDataBindField(

Comment: Can you add some detail around your SQL table setup please? It's because the column isn't being returned directly, I'll edit with a guess.

Comment: my table setup isn't any different then the fiddle i provided in my question

Comment: @user13814 Sorry, I missed that - As it's a straight table, the above edited select should do you. Just select the columns you need, filter with a `WHERE` clause if required and then the `FruitWebsite` and `FruitTitle` columns will be available to your GridView

Comment: thanks for help, I am using this one now, http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/

Answer (score 1):

While @RemarkLima showed you a better solution, you can render HTML in the GridView by setting `HtmlEncode="False"` which is `True` by default

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: I already tried that but it's not working, if you look at older questions of mine please, thanks

Comment: `HtmlEncode`is the way to go because I see you had 3 links in one row. Probably precede your links with `http://`

Comment: in my real project, I do have https:// still didn't worked, however, I think I need this one, http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/